# How to guarantee same library versions for Compile and Test configurations

Tags: unit-testing, dependencies, sbt, dependency-management

I have a medium-sized *sbt* project (~20 sub-projects, ~50 direct dependencies, ~400 transitive dependencies). I'm preparing the project to enable unit-testing [0]. I've run into strange problems and noticed that the exact versions used for certain dependencies differ between the `Compile` and `Test` targets, i.e. unit tests (`sbt test`) run with different versions of libraries than the project directly (`sbt run`).

I produced a diff between the output of `sbt Compile/dependencyList` [1] and `sbt Test/dependencyList` and see about 50 dependencies with differing versions. I know that I can use the `dependencyOverride` settings, but it seems impractical to do manually for hundreds of dependency. I would also have to update that list every time we would like to update our direct dependencies.

What is the intended way to handle this situation? I.e. how can I make sure that I am using the the same versions of dependencies during unit tests as when running in production?

[0]: Better late than never! :)

[1]: `dependencyList` is a command from [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph).

Answer (score 1):

Consider first confirming whether dependency hell is indeed the cause of the issue. One way we might do that is by running tests of a fat jar which includes all the runtime dependencies.

Add `sbt-assembly` to plugins and then define the following custom command:

```
commands += Command.command("testWithFatJar") { state =>
    "set assembly / test := {}" ::
    "assembly" ::
    "set Test / fullClasspath := Attributed.blank((assembly / assemblyOutputPath).value) :: (Test / fullClasspath).value.toList" ::
    "test" :: state
}
```

Note how we first assemble the fat jar, and then prepend it to the test classpath with

```
Test / fullClasspath := Attributed.blank((assembly / assemblyOutputPath).value) :: (Test / fullClasspath).value.toList
```

such that it is in the first position. Here we exploit JVM's [classpath ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#JSWOR590) property

> The order in which you specify multiple class path entries is
>   important. The Java interpreter will look for classes in the
>   directories in the order they appear in the class path variable

which means if we have same classes on the classpath, then the first one encountered will be used.

Location of the fat jar is provided by `assemblyOutputPath` task:

```
inspect assembly::assemblyOutputPath
[info] Task: java.io.File
[info] Description:
[info]  output path of the fat jar
```

Now executing `testWithFatJar` should run of the following test classpath:

```
sbt:how-to-guarantee-same-library-versions-for-compile-and-test-configurations> show Test / fullClasspath
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/how-to-guarantee-same-library-versions-for-compile-and-test-configurations/target/scala-2.12/how-to-guarantee-same-library-versions-for-compile-and-test-configurations-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/how-to-guarantee-same-library-versions-for-compile-and-test-configurations/target/scala-2.12/test-classes)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/code/stackoverflow/how-to-guarantee-same-library-versions-for-compile-and-test-configurations/target/scala-2.12/classes)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.12.8.jar)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/.ivy2/cache/org.scalatest/scalatest_2.12/bundles/scalatest_2.12-3.0.5.jar)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/.ivy2/cache/org.scalactic/scalactic_2.12/bundles/scalactic_2.12-3.0.5.jar)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.12.8.jar)
[info] * Attributed(/Users/mario_galic/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.12/bundles/scala-xml_2.12-1.0.6.jar)
```

Note how `*-assembly-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` is in the first position. Once we confirm dependency hell is the cause, then we could start thinking what permanent build modifications are necessary to address it.

Comment: I don't know whether what I encountered is considered "dependency hell", but I can confirm that indeed differing dependency versions were the culprit. The application was compiled against an older version of _Play_ than tests were run with. The applications code would not even compile with the newer version. Downgrading the additional test dependencies solved the problem. How can I make sure I'm not going to run into any more problems like this?

Comment: For now, I simply moved the test-only dependencies to the _Compile_ configuration, so they're also going to be in the built assembly unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my script that detects dependencies (and their versions) that are only present in the production configuration, but are not in the test configuration.

It relies on having the [dependency graph SBT plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-dependency-graph) installed.

I integrated this to our CI and made it fail the build if any production only dependencies are detected.

```sh
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                             

# http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/                                                                                                                                            
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

echo Getting dependencyList for production config
sbt "-Dsbt.log.noformat=true" dependencyList > dependency-list-production-raw.txt

echo Getting dependencyList for test config
sbt "-Dsbt.log.noformat=true" test:dependencyList > dependency-list-test-raw.txt

clean_up_dependency_list () {
  # non GNU sed version (less readable IMHO)                                                                                                                                                            
  # sed -n 's/[[:space:]]*\[info\][[:space:]]*\([^:]\{1,\}:[^:]\{1,\}:[^:]\{1,\}\)\s*$/\1/p' | sort | uniq                                                                                              
  sed --regexp-extended -n 's/^\s*\[info\]\s*([^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+)\s*$/\1/p' | sort | uniq
}

clean_up_dependency_list < dependency-list-production-raw.txt > dependency-list-production.txt

clean_up_dependency_list < dependency-list-test-raw.txt > dependency-list-test.txt


echo Dependencies in dependency-list-production.txt: "$(wc -l < dependency-list-production.txt)"
echo Dependencies in dependency-list-test.txt: "$(wc -l < dependency-list-test.txt)"

dependencies_only_in_prod=$(comm -23 dependency-list-production.txt dependency-list-test.txt)

if [ -n "$dependencies_only_in_prod" ]; then
    cat <<EOF                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    ERROR: Dependencies that are _not present in test_                                                                                                                                                  
    configuration detected!                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    This may signal a problem where a _different_ (older?) version of                                                                                                                                   
    a dependency will be used in production than what would be used in                                                                                                                                  
    production.                                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    Offending dependencies that are present  _only in prod_:                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$dependencies_only_in_prod                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    Full list of dependencies in test:                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$(cat dependency-list-test.txt)                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    List of dependencies in production:                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
$(cat dependency-list-production.txt)                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
EOF                                                                                                                                                                                                     

    exit 1
fi
```